# Disable default behavior for event resizing in the FullCalendar plugin

Tags: jquery, fullcalendar

When you resize an event, shrinking it, at a certain size it replaces the ending time of the event with the title of the event.
I would like it to always keep the time interval and just hide the title, keeping the event editable. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have to edit the core files of fullCalendar to achieve this. in `function renderSlotSegs` find the comment

> // not enough room for title, put it in the time

and edit it according to your needs

to keep time and remove title you need to remove this:

```
eventElement.find('div.fc-event-time')
    .text(formatDate(event.start, opt('timeFormat')) + ' - ' + event.title);
eventElement.find('div.fc-event-title').remove();
```

and replace with this:

```
eventElement.find('div.fc-event-title')
    .text(formatDates(event.start, event.end, opt('timeFormat')));    
eventElement.find('div.fc-event-time').remove();
```